# Preference Shares and free float

Tags: indexing

I am calculating the free float of shares included in an index, would the preference shares be counted as part of free float?

Comment: No, of course not. The preference shares are a different class of shares from the ordinary shares. The index includes let us say ordinary shares of XXX company. The calculation of free float is about how many ordinary shares of XXX are available for investment, it does not look at other kinds of shares.

Comment: Thank you very much!